# DynamoDBMapper - Unable to create a String Set

Tags: java, exception, amazon-dynamodb

I am using DynamoDBMapper to model and persist my entities to DynamoDB.  I have a simple entity with a few properties, including one that is to be a `java.util.Set` of `java.lang.String` objects.  However, when I request table creation I see the following warning:

```
WARN  [com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardModelFactories] Marshaling a set of non-String objects to a DynamoDB StringSet. You won't be able to read these objects back out of DynamoDB unless you REALLY know what you're doing: it's probably a bug. If you DO know what you're doing feelfree to ignore this warning, but consider using a custom marshaler for this instead.
```

If I try and add a value to this property then save my entity, I get this exception:

```
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: 
  One or more parameter values were invalid: 
  An string set  may not be empty 
  (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: a6ada7e0-ea45-4826-bff3-78ebbaf6c399)
```

The DynamoDBMapper documentation clearly states that `Set`s of `String`s are supported.  My entity looks something like this:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = Constants.TABLE_NAME)
public class ItemRecord implements Serializable {

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -554992528076340433L;

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private String creatorIdentifier = null;

    @DynamoDBTyped(DynamoDBAttributeType.SS)
    private Set<String> itemIdentifiers = new HashSet<>();

    // (More attributes here, including partition and range keys)
    ...
}
```

And my table creation code looks something like this:

```
ArrayList<AttributeDefinition> attrs = new ArrayList<>();
attrs.add(new AttributeDefinition().withAttributeName("pk").withAttributeType(ScalarAttributeType.S));
attrs.add(new AttributeDefinition().withAttributeName("sk").withAttributeType(ScalarAttributeType.S));

GlobalSecondaryIndex reverseIndex = new GlobalSecondaryIndex().withIndexName(Constants.GSI_REVERSE_INDEX)
        .withProvisionedThroughput(new ProvisionedThroughput(1L, 1L))
        .withKeySchema(new KeySchemaElement().withAttributeName("sk").withKeyType(KeyType.HASH),
                new KeySchemaElement().withAttributeName("pk").withKeyType(KeyType.RANGE))
        .withProjection(new Projection().withProjectionType(ProjectionType.ALL));

CreateTableRequest req = this.mapper.generateCreateTableRequest(ItemRecord.class)
        .withProvisionedThroughput(new ProvisionedThroughput(1L, 1L)).withAttributeDefinitions(attrs)
        .withGlobalSecondaryIndexes(reverseIndex);
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?  I'm using version 1.11.696 of the AWS Java SDK.

Comment: I think you may have two problems here. The first one, I don't understand (I don't see a problem). But the second one is fairly self-explanatory - you are not allowed to have an empty set. That's an inherent limitation of DynamoDB which is well-documented. If the set is empty, just don't set this attribute at all.

Comment: @NadavHar'El yes, I am aware that I cannot have an empty set.  In my code I am explicitly adding values to that set before saving.  That is why I'm so confused by this error.  The set is *not* empty.

Comment: So can you share a complete code snippet that demonstrates how you do the write? Maybe there's just an error there?

Comment: I believe you have already referred to the [Java SDK docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.html). The example has an implementation of `Set<String>`. You can also have a look at the [Javascript SDK Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html). Just `Ctrl + F` and look for `ValidationException`. There are plenty of notes giving reasons for this Exception to occur.

Answer (score 0):

`DynamoDB does not support empty sets`, however, empty string and binary values are allowed within a set.

It might be confusing because, on the one hand, empty sets are not supported; on the other hand, `Lists` and `Maps` can be stored with empty content.

DynamoDb treats Set and List, Map differently.

- `Set` can be represented by multiple scalar values. The set types are string set, number set, and binary set.
- `List and Map` are represented as document type. That type can represent a complex structure with nested attributes, such as what you would find in a JSON document.

From a Java point of view, Sets and Lists are perceived as general collection types. However, within the context of DynamoDB, these entities assume distinct roles tailored to specific purposes.